# Нотификация о смене часового пояса

Tags: windows, winapi, часовые-пояса

Мне в приложении нужно отловить смену часового пояса. Как это сделать?

Опытным путем было обнаружено, что при смене часового пояса, окну присылается `WM_TIMECHANGE`. В MSDN описания такого поведения я не обнаружил. Насколько правильный путь мониторинг этого сообщения?

Comment: @gregzakharov Без конкретизации. `Как получить уведомление о смене часового пояса`. В том же сервисе мне ничто не мешает создать окно. Мне нужно отловить момент смены часового пояса в запущенном приложении

Comment: @gregzakharov Таймером? Вы серьезно? Тогда вопросов больше не имею.